# is there any way to pass parameter for art_work for t300x300 image?

Tags: python, django, soundcloud

How to get t300*300 image in django template .

my code :
view :

```
client = soundcloud.Client(client_id="==================================");
    tracks = client.get('/tracks', order='hotness', limit=4) 
    val={"tracks":tracks}    
    return render_to_response('music/tracks.html',val)
```

In .html file

```
<img src="{{ track.artwork_url }}">
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking here?

Comment: this code gives default image (large) but i need t300x300 size image and please you dont votedown if you are not able to understand this question

Comment: It's up to you to provide a clear question. This question isn't clear at all. You want to get the image at `track.artwork_url` and resize it to a 300x300 thumbnail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [django-sorl-thumbnail](https://github.com/sorl/sorl-thumbnail), a very handy tool to resize images.

Some of the features include

- Very simple syntax
- Can use CSS to manipulate images

The usage is extremely simple:

```
{% load thumbnail %}
{% thumbnail track.artwork_url "300x300" crop="center" as im %}
    <img src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}">
{% endthumbnail %}
```

Comment: but i don't want to use thumbnail.
i have new Question.  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258191/getting-template-syntax-error-in-django-template

Answer (score 0):

You'll either have to find some way to resize the original images, although Django doesn't provide any built-in mechanism to do this, so check [this page](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/ThumbNails) for some options, or you can just ask the browser to resize it by using parameters on the `<img>` tag like...

```
<img width="300" height="300" src="{{ track.artwork_url }}">
```