# getting template syntax error in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

my code in view :

```
tracks = client.get('/tracks', order='hotness', limit=4)   
artwork_url=[]
for track in tracks:
    artwork_url.append(str(track.artwork_url).replace("large", "t300x300"))        


val={"tracks":tracks,"artwork_url":artwork_url}    
return render_to_response('music/tracks.html',val)
```

in .html

```
{% for track in tracks %} 
<li>
    <div class="genre-image">
        <img src="{{   artwork_url[forloop.counter] }}">
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Error:

```
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError 
Exception Value:  Could not parse the remainder: '[forloop.counter]' from 'artwork_url[forloop.counter]'
```

Comment: Are the elements of tracks immutable? If not, then just append to track variable instead of artwork_url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your `artwork_url` is a list, the reasonable way would be to access it like this:

`artwork_url.forloop.counter`

but it won't work. The Django template language isn't *that* advanced unfortunately.

You should access it like this.

```
{% for track in tracks %} 
<li><div class="genre-image">
<img src="{{ track.artwork_url }}">
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

But that requires that the tracks are mutable and require you to change it in the backend.

So if you're not able to modify the track you'd have to implement a custom template filter something like this

`{{ track.artwork_url|myFormatter:'t300' }}`

A very small and simple formatter:

```
@register.filter(name='myDate')
def myFormatter(value, arg):
    if arg == 't300':
        arg = 't300x300'
    return str(value).replace("large", arg)
```